# How to get list of preinstalled Python packages with their version number?

Tags: python, pip

By using `pip list` I can get list of what packages have been installed into my Python. However, Python comes with list of preinstalled packages as well. Why does pip not list these? How do I get list of these packages? And how do I know if I need to upgrade them?

Comment: I believe you're talking about the standard lib. They are part of Python, and are not upgraded separately from Python itself. So, when you update from Python 3.8.3 to 3.8.4, for example, you are updating the std lib too.

Comment: I see, I did not know that. Is there anyway to get list of what this standard library contains as a list with description of what each does in my command window? We can do something like this with pip list or pip search for Pypi packages.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Answer (score -1):

In the interactive shell, try

```py
help('modules')
```

Comment: This includes non-stdlib modules (I am not downvoter)